# How to remap C-w to quit emacs without saving?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

Similar to how I close tabs in Chrome, I would like emacs to behave as if I pressed C-x C-c when I press C-w alone. Is that possible? I don't care if C-w was previously used to do some command. I am okay with overriding that.

I tried this:

`(define-key map (kbd "C-w") 'kill-emacs)`

But this seems like it's invalid. I get:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/user/.emacs’:

Symbol's value as variable is void: map

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

Answer (score 2):

You got it almost right. The error indicates that you tried to use a variable called `map` which isn’t defined; probably you copied it from some code where there was a variable called `map`. You probably want to use `global-map` instead; this is a variable which is predefined, and it holds the global key map:

```lisp
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-w") 'kill-emacs)
```

Additionally, you could also call `global-set-key` instead of `define-key`:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-w") 'kill-emacs)
```

`global-set-key` isn’t very much faster to type, but it does have the advantage that it can also be called interactively during an Emacs session.

For more information, I recommend reading [chapter 49.3.6 Rebinding Keys in Your Init File](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html) in the Emacs manual. You can also read the manuals inside of Emacs; type `C-h i` to open the Info viewer.

Comment: It seems like that does not work for me. Maybe it's because I am using evil mode?

When I press C-w, it shows C-w at the bottom left but doesn't do anything. I guess it is waiting for me to add in another command there? When I do C-w <enter> it says C-w RET is undefined. C-w C-w doesn't work either.

Comment: Apparently you have bound `C-w` to a keymap, rather than to a single command. This makes it a prefix key for longer commands. You should be able to get a list with `C-w C-h`.

Comment: You are correct. The `evil` package does that. When I press `C-w C-h` I see this:


>     `evil-motion-state-minor-mode' Minor Mode Bindings Starting With C-w:
>     key             binding
>     ---             -------
>     
>     C-w C-b         evil-window-bottom-right
>     C-w C-c         evil-window-delete
>     C-w C-f         ffap-other-window



Now the question is how to unbind these and just bind C-w to quit?

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988406/unbinding-evils-c-w-mappings

(eval-after-load "evil-maps"
  (dolist (map '(evil-motion-state-map
                 evil-insert-state-map
                 evil-emacs-state-map))
    (define-key (eval map) "\C-w" nil)))

This unmaps the C-w prefix that evil minor mode uses. After that I can use `global-set-key` to remap C-w to anything and it works. Thank you!

(I could not edit the comment above because I was rate-limited trying to format the block code in there).

Comment: You should add that as an answer to your question, and accept it. Also, you should get rid of the explicit call to `eval`; it’s a code smell. Instead of iterating over a list of names, iterate over the values instead: `(dolist (map (list evil-motion-state-map …)) (define-key map …))`.